# Strange Callback Error PHP 5.4.30

Tags: php, callback, closures

I have the same exact PHP file on our development, and production servers. Both servers are running the same version of PHP, same modules, same interpreter, etc. Only the development server runs the code successfully. I have no idea what's causing this. I would normally chalk this up to a PHP versioning discrepancy, but that's not the case.

Both servers are running PHP 5.4.30.

**Here is the code in question:**

```
$inputArray = array('Tuesday' => null, 'Friday' => null, 'Monday' => null, 'Thursday' => null, 'Wednesday' => null);

$desiredIndexOrder = array('Monday' => 5, 'Tuesday' => 4, 'Wednesday' => 3, 'Thursday' => 2, 'Friday' => 1);

uksort($inputArray, function($a, $b) use ($desiredIndexOrder) {
    return $desiredIndexOrder[$a] > $desiredIndexOrder[$b] ? -1 : 1;
});

echo print_r($inputArray);
```

**Development output (Correct):**

> Array ( [Monday] => [Tuesday] => [Wednesday] => [Thursday] => [Friday] => ) 1

**Production Output:**

> Warning: uksort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in /home/friendso/public_html/test.php on line 9
>   Array ( [Tuesday] => [Friday] => [Monday] => [Thursday] => [Wednesday] => ) 1

Writing the callback as an actual function fixes the issue, but I'm curious as to what could cause this.

Comment: Have you ran the above code in isolation?

Comment: I have the code running in an independent php file on each server. No other software is involved. This is the entire contents of each file (not including the opening and closing php tags of course).

Comment: Works well for me.(5.5.14)

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused as to why this is a thing.

Comment: Compare your PHP configs. `diff -u <(php -i) <(ssh other.server.tld php -i)`

Comment: Here is the diff file. http://pastebin.com/sBPqk5mh

Comment: One of the servers is running the 'eAccelerator' extension which does some form of opcode caching. I would wager that that extension is the source of the trouble.

Comment: Thanks again @Sammitch. I'll try disabling and see what happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sammitch pointed out in a comment to my original question, eAccelerator was indeed the issue (not sure exactly why). To disable eAccelerator, I made these changes in my php.ini file, and restarted Apache.

```
eaccelerator.enable 0
eaccelerator.optimizer 0
```

The code now works as intended.